# крашится приложение Android (из String в int Java)

Tags: java, android, строки

Не пойму почему крашится приложение. Вроде все правильно написано.

```
switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.button:
                        String a = editText.getText().toString();
                        int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
                        int b = i/160;
                        int c = i/25;
                        textView.setText(b);
                        textView3.setText(c);
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.muka);
                        break;
                }
```

Comment: приведите текст ошибки

Comment: unfortunately , kitchenConverter has stopped

Comment: что пишет в логах?

Comment: для метода setText() нужно обратное приведение к String - `textView.setText(c + "")` как простейшее, но не самое правильное

Comment: спасибо) вот уж упустил из виду, так упустил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как видно из [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) есть два метода `setText`

1. `void setText (int resid)` принимает `id` строкового ресурса из `strings.xml`
2. `void setText (CharSequence text)` принимает `String`

В вашем случае т.к вы передаёте `int` приложение пытается найти строковый ресурс с данным ему id, поэтому и приложение крашиться.

Вам надо написать так:  `textView.setText(String.valueOf(b));`